# validation for textarea using CKeditor in yii

Tags: yii

I have one textfield and one textarea with CKeditor using yii framework. validation for textfield is working but validation for textArea is not working.can please any one help me..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us related code, what you had tried yet ?

Comment: please define *not working*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean clientside validation is not working. This is because Yii validation is triggered before CKEditor updates the textarea.

You can let CKEDITOR update the textarea before validating, and clientside/ajax validation will work as expected:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,   // one or both
    'enableClientValidation' => true, // one or both
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,   // optional
        'beforeValidate' => new CJavaScriptExpression('function(form) {
            for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) { 
                CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
            }
            return true;
        }'),
    ),
)); ?>
```